# linq remove item from object array where property equals value

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If i have

```
IEnumberable<Car> list
```

and i want to remove an item from this list based on a property of the car

i want something like:

```
list.RemoveWhere(r=>r.Year > 2000)
```

does something like this exist ?

i am doing this over and over so i want to avoid copying the list each time to just remove one item

Comment: Is it a `List<Car>` or just an `IEnumerable<Car>`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`IEnumberable` is immutable, but you can do something like this:

```
list = list.Where(r=>r.Year<=2000)
```

or write an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Predicate<T> predicate)
{ 
    return query.Where(e => !predicate(e));
}
```

Comment: @ooo IEnumerable is immutable, so you can't simple add or remove items, it's impossible. Of course you could just use a List, but it is not possible to say if this would be faster. If you do this over and over, keep the deferred execution in mind.

Answer (score 21):

Very late to the party but for any one would comes across this problem, here is a cleaner solution:

```
MyList.RemoveAll( p => p.MyProperty == MyValue );
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but IEnumerable<T> does not have this method. You will have to first ensure the collection is a List<T> type.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with `IEnumerable<T>`, how about Where?

```
list = list.Where(car => car.Year <= 2000);
```

If you are working with `ICollection<T>` and you not just get a filtered result but really intend to manipulate the source collection, you can create an own tailor made extension for collection:

```
  public static class CollectionExtensions {
     public static ICollection<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        List<T> toRemove = collection.Where(item => predicate(item)).ToList();
        toRemove.ForEach(item => collection.Remove(item));
        return collection;
     }
  }
```